# How to find depth of property?

Tags: c#, recursion, hierarchy

```cs
public class CategoryInModel
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public CategoryInModel Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class like above. I want to get depth of the Parent object.

Parent object can have various depths.
Like:

Parent.Parent.Parent

or

Parent.Parent

How can I find the depth of the parent object?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the logic that a model's depth will be 1 + the parent depth:

```
public class CategoryInModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CategoryInModel Parent { get; set; }

    public int Depth => 1 + ParentDepth;
    public int ParentDepth => Parent?.Depth ?? 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int GetDepth (CategoryInModel cat, int depth = -1)
{
    if (cat == null)
        return depth;
    else
        return GetDepth(cat.Parent, depth + 1);
}
```

And then to use:

```
var mod = new CategoryInModel { Parent = new CategoryInModel { Parent = new CategoryInModel { Parent = new CategoryInModel() } } };

Console.WriteLine(GetDepth(mod));
```